# Deleting channels, and only running code if a USER, not BOT reacts to a message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a ticketing system in which a user does `.ticket`.
I'm having an issue where 'bot' doesn't have the attribute 'delete_channel', and I also want to make it so the bot ignores the reaction if a bot reacts to the message, but acknowledges that a normal guild member has reacted to it.
Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
  global ticket_channel
  name = "tickets"
  category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
  guild = ctx.message.guild
  ticket_id = randint(0, 100)
  ticket_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"ticket-0{ticket_id}", category=category)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Tickets", description="Support will be with you shortly.\nTo close this ticket, react with :lock:.")
  message = await ticket_channel.send(embed=embed)
  await message.add_reaction(emoji="\N{LOCK}")

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.Member):
  if reaction.message.channel != ticket_channel:
    return
  if reaction.emoji == "\N{LOCK}":
    await bot.delete_channel(ticket_channel)
```

I've been trying for a while to figure out the issue, but I'm clueless.

Comment: You'll want to use `wait_for` to wait for the reaction.  `wait_for` takes a `check` function that you can use to ignore certain reactions.  [See this function factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684043/reaction-handling-in-discord-py-rewrite-commands/58684374#58684374) I wrote that lets you create such functions dynamically in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're asking several questions here:

> I'm having an issue where 'bot' doesn't have the attribute 'delete_channel'

The bot does not have a `delete_channel()` function. However, a `Discord.TextChannel` class has a `.delete()` function ([shown in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete)).

> and I also want to make it so the bot ignores the reaction if a bot reacts to the message

#### Alternative 1

Every user, including bot users, have the attribute `.bot`. You can use that to check if the user is a bot, and if so, return the function early.

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if user.bot: return
    # Code goes here
```

Note that this listens for all reactions, not just that specific message; thus comes:...

#### Alternative 2

As Patrick Haugh mentions, you could use the `discord.Client.wait_for()` function ([doc link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)) and parse a function to as the `check` argument of the function.

```
reaction, user = bot.wait_for('reaction', check=lambda reac: reac.author == ctx.author)
```

*Note that this approach doesn't add this code under any event (as in the first alternative), except the command event. It will only be run once per command received unless put in a loop of some sorts.